# Match the single letter x, that is placed immediately right after a number

Tags: c#, regex

I need C# regex so it matches letter X right after number. P.S. 12XX should not match (because of XX).

For example, "This is ABC 15x DEF", it should match "15x"

Comment: And what have you tried? Why should we make your work?

Comment: [`(?i)(?<=\d)x(?!x)`](https://regex101.com/r/HqklcA/1/) should work for you.

Comment: No :( it matches only X, I need also to match number before X

Comment: At the very least, it's your responsibility to think about the problem and make it clear what you want. You haven't done so. What's the intended result for `15xy`? What about `15x.`? What about `15x15`? What about `15x-20x`?

Comment: @Vnuuk: [`(?i)\b\d+x(?!x)`](https://regex101.com/r/HqklcA/2) should work then

Comment: @Vnuuk: As well as replying in comments (or instead of) you should update your question with new information you give people. You're question says explicitly "Match the single letter x" but in comments you are saying you also want to match the number before the x. If the latter is the case then update your question to reflect the correct information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is the following regex:

```
[\d]+x[^x]
```

This matches 1 or more digits, followed by the literal letter "x" and anything that is *not* x.

Feel free to replace `x` with `[a-z]` or `[a-zA-Z]` if you want any lowercase / uppercase letter instead of a specific letter x. You can also replace the last part, the negated set `[^x]`, with the aforementioned replacements (resulting in `[^a-z]` or similar).

Also, have a look at regexr.com for instructions how to use regex.

//EDIT: to cover all possible cases (as discussed in the comments) use the following regex:

```
[\d]+x(?=$|[^x])
```

The aforementioned, first version of the regex wouldn't match if the input string was `15x`, because there is no "letter other than x" afterwards (which is what `[^x]` asks) - there's simply nothing at all, i.e. the string doesn't match.

The "new" regex, however, asks whether the "character" after the match is either not x, or the end of the string (which can be matched with `$`).

It is also viable to use negative lookahead (`(?!something)`) as in @Justinas Marozas answer, which only matches if `something` doesn't match after the string (therefore *"negative"*). It also doesn't include `something` in the matched string / result (therefore *"lookahead"*).

The final regex would, therefore, be:

```
[\d]+x(?!x)
```

Using the second regex mentioned at the beginning of this edit yields the same results and is just as correct, though - it's just a little longer.

Thanks to @hvd for the feedback on and improvements to my answer!

Comment: This wouldn't match if the input is exactly `15x`, because `x` is not followed by a character other than `x`: it's not followed by any character at all.

Comment: How about example string in the question?

Comment: @hvd `[\d]+x[^x]*$`, then

Comment: @PixelMaster That would reject `This is abc 15x defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`. I don't know whether it's correct to reject that.

Comment: @hvd goddamnit :D How about `[\d]+x(?=$|[^x])`, then? lookahead so that the following letter isn't included.

Comment: @PixelMaster That should work (aside possibly from cases the OP should update the question for), but `(?!x)` instead of `(?=$|[^x])` as in Justinas Marozas's answer is functionally equivalent and simpler :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting 15x be surrounded by white space:

```
@"\b\d+x\b"
```

If you're not expecting 15x be surrounded by whitespace:

```
@"(?<!\d)\d+x(?!x)"
```

`\b` - word boundary; `\d` - digit;

`(?<!pattern)` - negative lookbehind; `(?!pattern)` - negative lookahead;

[Shorthand character reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)

[Look ahead/behind reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

And if you want to also catch 15X - pass `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` flag or replace `x` with `[Xx]`.